# How does this site know I'm a scraper?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape results from [this web form](https://eservices.landregistry.gov.uk/www/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOKNjSxMDA1NjDwsjM3MDTxN3dyNDUNMjQ1MjIEKIvEocDckpD84NU8_XD8KTZm_m6OBp7GTv7e7caCRgYEZhgJUcyyMCCgAuQOswAAHcDTQ9_PIz03VL8iNqPDMDEgHAAblRA0!/dl4/d5/L0lDU0lKSmdrS0NsRUpDZ3BSQ2dwUkNTQS9ZSVVJQUFJSUlJTU1JS0VFQUFDR09HT0NHSUJKRkpGQkpORE5EQk5ISUVBTExBISEvNEczYUQyZ2p2eWhDa3lGTU5RaWt5RktOUmprS2NhZ21Rb2dnL1o3XzMyODQxMTQySDgzNjcwSTVGRzMxVDUzOFY0LzAvaWJtLmludi8zMDUyODkzMDU5MDYvc3BmX0FjdGlvbk5hbWUvc3BmX0FjdGlvbkxpc3RlbmVyL3NwZl9zdHJ1dHNBY3Rpb24vITJmTHJJbnNwaXJlSWRJbml0LmRv/) (sample ID: 15740175). Actually I'm sending a POST request from Scrapy, in the same way that the form does.

I am working from a non-blocked IP - I can make a request successfully from Firefox on this machine. I'm using Firefox with JavaScript and cookies disabled, so the site doesn't require either JS or cookies to return results.

This is my Scrapy code:

```
allowed_domains = ['eservices.landregistry.gov.uk']
start_urls = []
_FORM_URL = "http://eservices.landregistry.gov.uk/www/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/" \
            "hc7LDoIwEAXQb-ELOrQFu60EgSgg8hDYEFQ0GHksCIZ-veBODTK7Sc69MyhFMU" \
            "rrvC9veVc2df6Y9lTNCGZUlik2GVFXYCkbg8iBQoCSESR_gCEv5Y8oBpr5d9ba" \
            "QxfvhNYHd-ENjtCxLTg44vy0ndP-Eh3CNefGoLMa-UU95tKvanfDwSJrd2sQDw" \
            "OoP-DzNsMLYPr9DWBmOCDHbKoCJSNbzfWwiKK2CvvyoF81LkkvDLGUgw!!/dl4" \
            "/d5/L0lDU0lKSmdwcGlRb0tVUW9LVVEhL29Gb2dBRUlRaGpFQ1VJZ0FJQUl5Rk" \
            "FNaHdVaFM0SldsYTRvIS80RzNhRDJnanZ5aERVd3BNaFFqVW81Q2pHcHhBL1o3" \
            "XzMyODQxMTQySDgzNjcwSTVGRzMxVDUzOFY0LzAvMjc0MzY5MTc0Njk2L3NwZl" \
            "9BY3Rpb25OYW1lL3NwZl9BY3Rpb25MaXN0ZW5lci9zcGZfc3RydXRzQWN0aW9uL" \
            "yEyZlFEU2VhcmNoLmRv/"

def start_requests(self):

    settings = get_project_settings()
    ids = ['15740175']
    for i, id in enumerate(ids):
        yield FormRequest(
            url=self._FORM_URL,
            formdata={
                'polygonId': id,
                'enquiryType': 'lrInspireId',
            },
            headers={
                'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
                'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5', '
                'Referer': ''
            }
        )

def parse(self, response):
    # do parsing here
```

But in the log I just see a 403 response. (NB, the site's robots.txt doesn't forbid scraping.)

I've used Charles to inspect the request sent by Scrapy, and all the request headers (including User-Agent) look identical to the request headers sent when I make the request in Firefox and get 200 back.

Presumably the site knows I'm a scraper and is blocking me, but how does it know? I'm genuinely mystified. I'm only sending one response, so it can't be to do with rate limiting or download delays.

Answer (score 0):

This site may be protected against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) (Cross Site Request Forgery). Also the action URL looks like having a [session token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) which prevents replay attacks. However scraping can be illegal and check with the owners of this site/ organization before accessing this site in such ways

Answer (score 0):

Just open page source HTML in browser and refresh it several times - you'll see that form action URL is changing every time, so it is dynamic URL while you try to use it as hard-coded. You should fetch HTML page with the form first and then send form data using current form action URL.